# Android - Turn switch "On" on ListView item click

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin

I have a custom listview in my `C#` Android app, each row contains a `textview`, `ImageView` and a `switch`. When a Listview item is clicked, I want to turn the row's item switch on.

**MainActivity:**

```
List<TableList> list = = new List<TableList>();
list.Add(new TableList("Germany"));
list.Add(new TableList("France"));
list.Add(new TableList("Finland"));
listView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = t.Name;
            if (selected == "France")
            {
                 // Turn the proper switch for France row ON
            }
        };
```

**ListAdapter and ListClass for the Listview:**

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableList>
{
    List<TableList> items;
    Activity context;
    public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<TableList> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override TableList this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CoinList, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CoinName).Text = item.Name;
         view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.n);

        If item is clicked set it on
        {
            view.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switch).SetOn 
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switch).SetOf
        }
        return view;
    }
}
public class TableList
{
    public string Name;
    public TableList(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I should set the Switch ON (in the `listView.ItemClick` event or in the `ListAdapter`) and I don't know how to set it to ON. Please help me to do so.

Comment: Once its on then what are you going to do with it, It sounds like you need to use the mvvm pattern and set such things from your view model

Comment: @TheGeneral Nothing, it is just a set of design so the user knows that he selected this item (instead of checkbox).

Comment: It sounds like you want to use mvvm, have a viewmodel that represents the list item,with a ischecked property that is set via the tapped command which will notify the switch

Comment: Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewSwitch) is my demo.

You can choose one to achieve your goal. I will show you how to do this by `ItemClick` event:

> When a Listview item is clicked, I want to turn the row's item switch on.

Because, `Switch` will grab the focus from `ViewGroup`. So, I remove the focus from `Switch` in the `MyAdapter`:

```
holder.ms.Focusable = false;//ms is Switch
```

Now, this is my `ItemClick` event( turn switch on while click the item):

```
private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
        var ll = e.View as LinearLayout;
        var sw = ll.GetChildAt(1) as Switch;
        if (sw.Checked)
        {
            sw.Checked = false;
            adapter.changeState((int)sw.Tag,false);
        }
        else
        {
            sw.Checked = true;
            adapter.changeState((int)sw.Tag, true);
        }
}
```

As we all know, `ListView` has reuse problem, so, I add a bool property to control the `Switch`'s state:

```
public class MyData:Java.Lang.Object {
    public MyData(string p,bool b) {
        this.position = p;
        this.isCheck = b;
    }
    public string position { get; set; }
    public bool isCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Below is `changeState` method:

```
internal void changeState(int position, bool v)
{
    mitems[position].isCheck = v;
    this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And this is `CheckedChange` event:

```
private void Ms_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var sm = sender as Switch;
    Log.Error("Ms_CheckedChange", (int)sm.Tag+"");
    if (e.IsChecked&&!mitems[(int)sm.Tag].isCheck)
    {
        mitems[(int)sm.Tag].isCheck = true;
        this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(!e.IsChecked&& mitems[(int)sm.Tag].isCheck)
    {
        mitems[(int)sm.Tag].isCheck = false;
        this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting a `NullException` here: `var sw = ll.GetChildAt(1) as Switch;`

Comment: Hi, I have changed my demo, please check it.

Comment: where is the `ItemClick` event of the Listview now ??

Comment: I have removed it.

Comment: It's all about the Listview event, so when an item is clicked the switch turns on. How can I know the selected item in the list now ? See my Listview `ItemClick` event in my code.

Comment: I have added the item click event, just updated the github, please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171623/discussion-between-wassim01-and-joe-lv-msft).